# Are there any specific traits in Italian which make it different from other Romance languages?

Tags: linguistic-typology, romance-languages, italian

Although Wikipedia says 'the [grammar is typical of the grammar of Romance languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language#Influence_and_derived_languages)', I suppose some ancient Italic (or perhaps even pre-italic) traits might prevail.

I am especially curious about syntax features, like subject-object relations in [Italian grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_grammar).

Comment: Italian syntax and grammar seems to be very much like French, at least when comparing with Spanish, which sounds superficially much more similar.

Answer (score 2):

Not syntax but it has a lot of geminates. It's very hard for all but the broadest syntactic and lexical patterns to last that long.

Comment: And almost all the geminates are the remains of deceased consonant clusters, which often show up in sister languages.

Answer (score 2):

Among the phenomena which could reasonably fit your requirement of being about subject/object relation, Italian allows passivization of causatives. I believe this is quite rare among Romance languages.

Compare the rare but completely acceptable

*La machina è stata fatta riparare a Gianni da Maria*

The car is been made repaired to Gianni by Maria

with

**La voiture a été faite réparé par Jean par Marie.*

which is completely impossible (in fact quite unthinkable, at least for this native speaker).

Answer (score 1):

*Standard Italian* has a pretty entrenched dinstinction between *passato remoto*, *passato prossimo* and *imperfetto*

- **passato remoto** ~ remote perfect/preterite complete actions in the past (from Latin perfect)
- **passato prossimo** ~ present perfect
- **imperfetto** ~uncompleted action (Latin imperfect)

In everyday usage speakers in the south of Italy tend to used *passato remoto* for *any kind of perfect*, which is more or less the same usage as in Classical Latin. On the other hand everyday usage in the north of Italy is *passato prossimo* for all kinds of perfect. Passo remoto is rare.

- the two-way distinction of **northern Italian** also applies to **French**, where passe simple is used both as a remote and present perfect, in contrast to imparfait. Passe simple (passato remoto) is rare, except in writing.

As fas as i know

- the three-way distinction in **Standard Italian** also applies to **Spanish**
- the two-way distinction in **southern Italian** (Classical Latin) also applies to **Portuguese**

Comment: Doesn't French have a three-way distinction, too? Imparfait, passé composé and passé simple?

Comment: ®robert sure, but passe simple is rarely used except in writing